# Function is being called when it is not supposed to be called

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, scheduling

There is a scheduled notification which is supposed to show after **5 seconds**. This scheduled notification is being called inside the `void initState` function. I'm using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to show notifications.

The notification is being shown exactly after **5 seconds**, so there is no problem there.

The problem is that there is another function that is supposed to be called when the notification is clicked. But this function is being called long before the notification even appears and I don't know how is this happening. I have tried different approaches to solve this problem but non works.

Be low is the code where all this is happening.

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initNotifSettings = new InitializationSettings(android, null);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initNotifSettings,
        onSelectNotification: whenNotificationSelect);

    showNotification();
  }

  Future whenNotificationSelect(String payload) async {
    print('Payload: $payload');
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notifications');
  }

  showNotification() async {
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel name', 'channel description');
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, null);

    var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
        DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 2));
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
      0,
      'Good morning!',
      'Greetings from me.',
      scheduledNotificationDateTime,
      platform,
      payload: 'Simple App',
    );
  }
}
```

**Note** The function `whenNotificationSelect` it needs to be called when notification is being clicked, but for other reasons that I don't know this function is being called immediately when the app starts. **I want** `whenNotificationSelect` to be called only when the notification is clicked not when the app starts.

Thank you, so much Love.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
onSelectNotification:(String payload) => whenNotificationSelect(String payload)
```

When you are not using (String payload) it means, the function will be triggered on null too. Whenever you have to pass arguments, use `(arguments)=> functionName(arguments)`